Caffeine Cache Get Latest Entry
I am using Caffeine Cache API in my application. Here is the configuration:
Caffeine<Object, Object> caffeineCacheBuilder() {
    return Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .initialCapacity(100)
    .expireAfterWrite(Duration.ofHours(50));
}

Is there any method to get the latest inserted entry into the cache?

You can query the policy for the expiration order (youngest in your case). Otherwise you would need to maintain your own insertion-order side mapping.
